# Line Conversions and Bsurfaces with Blender 2.69

Tags: modeling

- My problem is converting a path into a bezier, and a bezier back to a 
  Grease Pencil again (or path to Grease Pencil),
  since I need the handle assistance in *Edit mode* for those to get my shapes just right, and free handing with Grease
  Pencil isn't accurate enough for curves to start.
- From there, my second problem is turning at least 2 Grease Pencil Lines
  into the opposite edges of a corelative surface, using BSurfaces.
  I can't get Bsurfaces to run.

What state do 2 opposite beziers need to be in?
Do you have to start from grease pencil only?

How do I get Bsurfaces to show me the *Add Surface*
button, to draw it's extrapolation for me?

I've found
the buttons, keys and mouse click too confusing here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about converting back and forth between a grease pencil stroke and a curve, but you can create a surface from grease pencil strokes like this:

1. Enable *Bsurfaces* in *User preferences > Addons*
2. Create an empty mesh by adding a primitive and deleting all the geometry from *edit mode > <kbd>Delete</kbd>*:

   [image]
3. Add a new grease pencil layer in the *3D view > Properties region (<kbd>N</kbd>)* and select *Surface*:

   [image]
4. Still in edit mode, (editing the empty object) draw grease pencil strokes on the target object with <kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>:

   [image]
5. In the *Tool shelf* (<kbd>N</kbd> in the *3D view*), press *Add surface* in the *Bsurfaces panel*:

   [image] [image]